# OSM no Tiles / dont have .meta data

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openstreetmap

At first, what i am using:
Ubuntu 14.04 core server

And I used these two instructions:

At first I tried this instruction:
 https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/

Secondly I tried this:
https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/

First Problem:
So now i have a slippymap with only pink tiles. 
I also changed the Location in the Slippymaphtml (from localhost to my server)

Secondly i also have only one .meta data (A picture from the whole world) in my /var/lib/mod_tiles/ file although i downloaded germany and north-ireland and imported them into the database.

I also checked all my .conf files and compared them with a running VMWare System which im downloaded.
Last there weren't big differences, except some paths.

And everything worked fine, I still had to download some libs.
Only the map wont't work.

Maybe you guys can help me or give me some tips for which file maybe makes the problem.
If you need more Information pls tell me.
Thank you in advance.

Im also sorry for my english, it is still not the best.

Comment: Logs? Error messages? Any further information?

Comment: postgresql Log: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AlQbHL8aYRG0cy6WJav1bwcxmdE (here i still solved the Permission Problem) and Apache Log: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AlQbHL8aYRG0dC14uM7zh9XQEAA